# Screen Displays weird and then freezes

Tags: windows-7

The Problem is same as in this question

[Computer suddenly dies; screen displays weird flickering lines, then restarts](https://superuser.com/questions/569751/computer-suddenly-dies-screen-displays-weird-flickering-lines-then-restarts?newreg=57787bf517ef4d22bd4b692846a2a0b3)

The screen is almost similar as shown in the pic but not so dense. I would like to know if reinstalling the windows would fix the problem. I have win 7 currently installed. There was a problem with the motherboard and I recently got it repaired and the problem has started since then. The laptop does not have an external Graphics Card. It has Intel HD 3000. I have swapped the RAM in the 2 slots available.

Comment: Try using a live CD (Linux) to use the system. This will help us in pinning down the problem either to hardware or software. If it is a hardware problem then this issue will re-occur. If it is software problem you can re-install Windows 7

Comment: Looks like grafics ram crash, looks like this when the ram is too hot on gpu cards (in desktops). You need to describe when how and where and the timing on the problem? Adding the computers model and specs would also be useful?  If parts of the file items were corrupted , it likely to happen when making use of those files (running those programs). Corrupted files could cause a memory issue to manifest slowly but that would be rare.   You would not Need to re-install, there are other methods. >SFC /ScanNow Which checks the integrity of OS files, and Repair install which replaces the files.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Kali Linux on the system and now linux is working fine. Dont know if this is permanent or not, but if the problem re-appears then I will surely post back on this question.