# Is my computer damaged?

Tags: graphics-card

I smashed my laptop in the trackpad area, and immediately after, it died and restarted on its own. I have no doubt it wasn't an coincidence. I looked online, and I found a picture that looked exactly like my screen when it died: [Computer suddenly dies; screen displays weird flickering lines, then restarts](https://superuser.com/questions/569751/computer-suddenly-dies-screen-displays-weird-flickering-lines-then-restarts)

This never happened again. I want to know if this might have done permanent damage. I have a E series Sony VAIO laptop.

Comment: It's entirely possible damage was done.  Open up your laptop and inspect it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe so.   I've been building and troubleshooting computers for about 20 years.   That screenshot with your description of the accident clearly points to hardware damage.   If it were software or driver related, it would be completely different (you would be reading something about the conflict/problem).

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible for us to say, since we cant physically touch your computer.  More than likely, you have done physical damage to the motherboard.  If it is under warranty, send it to Sony and pray it is covered.